# I am the god who said no more! Who am I?

Tags: riddle

I am after and before
I am the god who said no more!
A fraudulent rose, now set free
The foundation sat upon me.

Who am I?

Hint:

> I refuse to move, though I'm casually roaming

Comment: is the speaker [after-and-before the "god"] mentioned in the second line, or is the speaker [that "god"]?

Comment: The speaker is that god. I'll make a minor edit for clarity.

Comment: I'm going with Gaia

Comment: Alls I can think is Atlas, but I can't fill in blanks enough to convince myself.

Comment: If anyone wants to post an answer with their interpretations, I can tell you which ones are along the right lines.

Comment: This has been solved, but I've added the hint I had planned to give if necessary, just in case future readers want it.

Comment: Since it doesn't seem like they will be solved, would it be inappropriate for me to edit an explanation of line 2 and the hint into the accepted answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have the actual answer this time! Very confident. You are

> Terminus

Explanation:

*I am after and before*

> A terminus is the beginning or end of something

*I am the god who said no more*

> Terminus declares "no more" in Ralph Waldo Emerson's poem of the same name.

*A fraudulent rose, now set free*

> The hacker Terminus, whose real name was Leonard Rose, was imprisoned for wire fraud for a year and a day.

*The foundation sat upon me*

> In Isaac Asimov's *Foundation* series, the Foundation is built on the planet Terminus at the edge of the galaxy.

Excellent riddle.

*I refuse to move, though I'm casually roaming*

> Terminus, as a god of boundary stones, forbade the removal of his marker from the future site if the temple of Jupiter. He was also a *Roman* god, and "casually roaming"="roamin".

Comment: Excellent! Your answer is correct, though your explanation for line 2 is wrong...

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing in explanations for line 2 and the hint, for the benefit of future readers. Please revert if you would rather I had not done this.

Answer (score 8):

Terrible guess: you are

> Peter

Reasoning:

> After and before: Peter can appear as a first or last name (both real and fictional people are named Peter Peter, even). Said no more: Peter Parker renounced his godhood and said he'd be Spiderman no more. A fraudulent rose, now set free: Peter "Pete" Rose, the baseball player, was imprisoned for tax fraud but is now set free. The foundation sat upon me: [Matthew 16:18](http://biblehub.com/matthew/16-18.htm)

Comment: This is easily the best one I've seen so far as far as matching the third line.

Comment: I love this! It's wrong, but brilliant, and you are thinking along the right lines for line 3.

Answer (score 0):

Answer

> Nothing or nothingness? Not sure about the third verse, though.

I am after and before

> Before and after existance - nothing, basically

I am the god who said no more!

> "God had no choice" as to whether or not to "start" the Universe, as i'm sure i read some philosopher say.

A fraudulent rose, now set free

> Not sure

The foundation sat upon me.

> You can only start building from scratch (foundations) by starting with/from nothing.

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning, please?

Comment: Edited. I'm on mobile, sorry if it looks funny

Comment: Interesting interpretation, but I'm afraid none of those are on track.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is

> Time

**Explaination**

I am after and before

> It was before our existence and will be even after our death because it don't stop

I am the god who said no more!

> When you lose it you can't get it back. The word 'said' here shows that it was past tense i.e. it is gone.

A fraudulent rose, now set free

> There had been a great discussion on time in physics. But now everything is decided how it works

The foundation sat upon me.

> It started with big bang.

Comment: Nice try, but I'm afraid not. (And I think time is still pretty mysterious)